# Tab Components not rendering -React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm hosting two tab components in a js  file.  If a render only tab router  its  working  perfectly. if i try to render inside View component its not  rendering tabs.

my RegisterHost.js  render method.

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>This is main home Component</Text>
    <Tab />
  </View>
);
```

}

Its  rendering only 'This is main Home Component'

if I comment View and text components. Its rendering Tab perfectly.

```
   render() {
    return (
      // <View>
      //   <Text>This is main home Component</Text>
        <Tab />
      //</View>
    );
  }
```

my Tab router config

```
  export const Tab = TabNavigator(
  {
    BankCustomerRegister: {
      screen: BankCustomerRegister,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Bank Customer"
      }
    },
    nonbankcustomer: {
      screen: NonCustomerRegister,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "New Customer"
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm not sure  where its going  wrong.
Is there something am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `style={{flex: 1}}` to the parent View of RegisterHost.js

Comment: Can you suggest some link where i  can learn complete flex usage related to React-native

Comment: Here are 3 links that helped me when I started using React Native :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html -

https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/understanding-react-native-flexbox-layout-7a528200afd4 -

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-layouts-in-react-native--cms-27418 -

Hope this will help ;)